# CSS: three background-image links: float one extreme left, one extreme right, and one centre?

Tags: css, css-float

I want to use CSS to build a navigational layout, for a series of blog posts, each of which is a chapter of a cartoon series:

```
<div with 500px width>-------------------------
-----------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------
<div>
<<previous          +more                >>next
</div>
</div>
```

The 'previous', 'next' and 'more' are all empty divs (but could be spans) with 50px width and background-image applied. They link to the relevant places.

I'm using CSS sprites to create nice hover effects, which also means I can't easily alter the width of each link without messing up the sprites.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to style the three divs to get 'previous' to float extreme left, 'more' to float centre, and 'next' to float right.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

---

Comment: What's the html structure of that part of the page?

Comment: have edited to clarify a bit, thanks...

Comment: could you post the actual html mark-up of that part of the page? Or post a demo at [JS Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), that we can work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just define the margin since I assume the container div will always be 500?

So something like

```
<div style="width: 500px">
<div style="float: left;">Previous</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: how ever many pixels it takes to center;">more</div>
<div style="float: right;">Next</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.previous {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-position: left; 
}
.more {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  background-position: center;
}
.next {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-position: right; 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work - the 'more' image is not centred, it's over to the LHS of its box.

Comment: Are you specifying `background-position:center;`?

Comment: Updated based on your clarifications.

Comment: it has `background-position: 0px 0px`, and `background-position: 50px 0px` on hover (because the image changes when you hover over it, hence using sprites in the first place)...